# Metal Detector Coil Design

Tags: frequency, inductance, coil, resonance

I have finally settled on a metal detector design on mine will be based on with one big issue,

(Tx wire diameter: 0.6mm, Rx wire diameter 0.3mm, 55 turns each)
[image: Design]

I would like to increase the coil size to around 11inches (~28 cm) instead of 16 cm in the orignal design with a wire diameter of 0.3 mm for each coil because I have plenty of it,

Instead of using smartphone, I will be adding an op-amp stage to add some gain to the signal and will use arduino to make sense of it,

What changes should I make to the number of turns and capacitor to achieve resonant frequency around 5 kHz and keep the inductance similar to the original design? **[Orignal Design](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Sensitive-VLF-METAL-DETECTOR-With-Smartphone-d/)** mentioned resonant frequency of 4.75 kHz but all online calculators I found have different opinions about it (excuse my lack of knowledge here) but I would like to be within 5 kHz to 6 kHz range,

How important is resonant frequency for metal detectors? as I don't have oscilloscope and I will be using my own logic, what should be a good coil design that fits these specifications:

- Should be 10 to 12 inches in diameter that will then molded into required D shape,
- Uses wire diameter of 0.3 mm
- Should work in 5 kHz to 6 kHz range

Note: Double D coil for VLF metal detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What changes should I make to the number of turns*

The area of the the coil's "aperture" is proportional to the coil's inductance so, if the area doubles (when you make the coil diameter bigger), then you can reduce the turns by the square root of 2. If the area rose by 3 times then reduce the turns by the square root of 3. These are approximate calculations because there can be other factors that might make this inexact.

This will roughly keep the inductance about the same as it was originally and be tuned with the original value of capacitor to the same frequency. I would urge you to get an oscilloscope though. Alternatively, make a little pick-up coil and put back-to-back diodes across it (as you have done with your receive coil) and listen to the pitch produced in headphones. Maybe you have good pitch hearing and you can tell that the operating frequency didn't change that much when you made the bigger transmit coil.

Comment: Thanks, i already came up with the idea of using earphones and listening to it but i thought it needs more precision which i might not be able to guess, what difference does wire gauge make? Will using 0.6mm vs 0.3mm produce (roughly) same results?

Comment: A free guitar tuner app for your phone should be able to measure the frequency.

Comment: Thinner wire @asim might not be a good idea because the transmit loop current might be in the region of several amps RMS even though the DC supply current is only tens of mA. It's all about a thing called Q-factor current magnification and, with thinner coil wire, you get more losses and less current amplification. For metal detectors I've designed and build I used solid copper wire that was over 2 mm diameter.